# Escaping xml encoded quotes in azure liquid mapping

Tags: json, xml, azure, dotliquid

I've been struggling for some time with the following problem. I have an xml which has to be transformed to json using liquid mapping on azure. Sometimes a node contains xml encoded double quotes, like this:

```
<node>
    <value>&quot;some string&quot;and the rest</value>
</node>
```

my liquid mapping looks like this:

```
"name":"{{ node.value }}"
```

The result of the mapping is a following error:

```
{
  "Code": "IncorrectLiquidTransformOutputType",
  "Message": "An error occurred while converting the transformed value to JSON. The transformed value is not a valid JSON. 'After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: s. Path '[205].node[9].value', line 32305, position 13.'",
  "Details": [
    {
      "Code": "IncorrectLiquidTransformOutputType",
      "Message": "{\"ClassName\":\"Microsoft.Azure.Function.Common.ErrorResponses.ErrorMessageException\",\"Message\":\"An error occurred while converting the transformed value to JSON. The transformed value is not a valid JSON. 'After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: s. Path '[205].node[9].name', line ....., position 13.'\",\"Data\":null,\"InnerException\":{\"ClassName\":\"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException\",\"Message\":\"After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: s. Path '[205].node[9].value'....",
      "Details": null,
      "InnerError": null
    }
  ],
  "InnerError": null
}
```

This means that the character " is properly decoded to double quote, and then it causes problems with the json. I need to keep this character like this:

```
"name":"\"some string\"and the rest"
```

any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same issue, but I convert the xml to json before passing it through the liquid transform. So the transformation gets a properly escaped json string:

```
"name":"William \"Billy\" Bob"
```

I tested the proposed solution above (which looks a bit weird since it replaces any occurrence with the same value), and at first it didn't do anything. However, after some fiddling around, I removed the first Replace and then it actually worked.

```
{{ node.value | Replace: '\"', '\"'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to escape them in the output?

"name":"{{ node.value | Replace: '\' , '\' | Replace: '\"', '\"'}}"